# Windows 10 won't boot after running CCleaner

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-registry, ccleaner

I have a dual boot PC (Ubuntu & Windows 10). Since a couple of days ago, I can't log into windows 10. The logo screen is displayed, but it never reaches the login screen. It goes dark after a couple of seconds.

It happened after I ran CCleaner. Unfortunately, I have not saved a copy of the registry. I have tried reinstalling, repairing and all sorts of ideas available online to fix Windows 10 using a bootable USB stick.

I can boot into my PC with my stick and open a command line. How can I check and fix registry errors on my installation?

**More information**

- `chkdsk /f` did not find any issues
- `sfc /scannow` returned `Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requeste operation`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the /r to chkdsk? Since you cannot enter recovery mode I suggest the following launch and setup cd of windows and enter the troubleshooter and try to recover it if not you can always reinstall windows without formatting on the same drive if there are sensitive data that needs to be recovered and then perform a fresh clean installation of windows . Alternative method which I do not recommend is set up a fresh copy of windows on a VM and export the Registry key to a USB and use copycon to replace the newly exported key with the corrupted one from command line .